# How to test if a list of periods forms a year

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a list of periods (dates) and I want to test if they forms a year 
Any idea how ? periods should not have holes or overlappings

Comment: Do you have any preliminary attempts to share? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: How do some dates form a year? Can you explain that, best with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two methods:

- You sort the array of ranges by start date, and then you check that each start of range is equal the end of the previous range + 1 day

or

- You create an array of 366 bool, then for each range you fill the array. If you fill a day that is already true, then there is an overlap. Last step you check that the array is full of `true`.

Now, in the end as always the implementation is more complex than I thought... The first method:

```
static bool IsFullRange(DateRange[] dateRanges, int year)
{
    // We shouldn't modify input parameters :-)
    // So we clone it
    dateRanges = (DateRange[])dateRanges.Clone();

    // Sort the array
    Array.Sort(dateRanges, (p, q) => p.Start.CompareTo(q.Start));

    // We skip dateRanges that are fully in previous years
    int i = Array.FindIndex(dateRanges, p => p.End.Year >= year);

    if (i == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // The dateRange starts after the first of the year
    if (dateRanges[i].Start > new DateTime(year, 01, 01))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // We skip the first element
    for (i = i + 1; i < dateRanges.Length; i++)
    {
        if (dateRanges[i].Start > new DateTime(year + 1, 01, 01))
        {
            // Already on another year
            break;
        }

        // Overlap
        if (dateRanges[i].Start <= dateRanges[i - 1].End)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Does the last range "covers" the end of the year?
    if (dateRanges[i - 1].End < new DateTime(year, 12, 31))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

With the `DateRange` that is

```
public class DateRange
{
    public readonly DateTime Start;
    public readonly DateTime End;

    public DateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }
}
```

And you use it like:

```
DateRange[] dateRanges = new[] 
{ 
    new DateRange(new DateTime(2015, 6, 7), new DateTime(2015, 12, 2)),
    new DateRange(new DateTime(2015, 12, 03), new DateTime(2016, 03, 02)),
    new DateRange(new DateTime(2014, 11, 21), new DateTime(2015, 6, 6)),
};

bool res = IsFullRange(dateRanges, 2015);
```

Note that the non-overlap and no-hole are tested only for the `year` given.

Comment: should read: sort the ranges based on their starting date. AND: To detect overlap in method2: check that no day is set a second time

Comment: Yep :-) But I was leaving that to the followup question "how do I sort date ranges" :-)

Comment: Oh, sorry for spoiling the party... ;)